# Botão só funcionar se passar o Id na URL no asp.net MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Estou com um problema na minha aplicação gerenciador de Cursos em asp.net MVC.

O cenário é o seguinte: Tenho uma tela onde o "Aluno" faz sua inscrição em um curso. Ao clicar no botão "inscrição", ele é associado a um curso e quantidade de vagas deste curso será decrementada. O Razor da tela é mais ou menos assim:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
       <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nome_Curso)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Sigla)
        </td>
        ...
        <td>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Inscricao", "Curso")">
                        <input type="submit" value="Inscrição" name="inscricao" class="inscricao btn btn-success" data-toggle ="modal", data-target="#modalaviso" data-inscricaoid="@item.CursoId" /></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>

}
```

Neste caso, só funciona se eu passar o Id como parâmetro na URL. Exemplo: minha URL de inscrição é **Cursos/Inscricao** só que assim o botão **não faz nada**. Agora se eu passar o parâmetro Id ele funciona, assim: **Cursos/Inscricao/1**.

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".inscricao").click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "~/Curso/Inscricao/" + $(this).data("inscricaoid"),
                    success: function() {
                        $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
                    }
                });
            });

        });
    </script>
}
```

Não quero ficar passando o Id na URL. Preciso que quando o "aluno" clicar no botão "inscrição" ele seja associado ao curso e as vagas decrementadas sem passar o Id na URL.

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/67178/desabilitar-um-bot%C3%A3o-no-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Também relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/67538/como-fazer-associa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-um-id-no-asp-net-mvc/67551#67551

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicamente, você está usando uma requisição Ajax cujo método é `POST`, mas você não está passando dados por `POST`.

Altere para o seguinte:

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".inscricao").click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "~/Curso/Inscricao/",
                    data: { inscricaoId: $(this).data("inscricaoid") }
                    success: function() {
                        $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
                    }
                });
            });

        });
    </script>
}
```

[Conforme o exemplo de *Action* que respondi aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/67538/como-fazer-associa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-um-id-no-asp-net-mvc/67551#67551), serão necessárias algumas alterações:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Inscricao(int inscricaoId)
{
    using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
    {

        // Aqui pegaria o aluno logado.
        var aluno = db.Alunos.FirstOrDefault(/* Aqui vai uma condição */);
        if (aluno == null) return View("Inscricao", db.Cursos.ToList());

        var curso = db.Cursos.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == inscricaoId);
        if (curso == null) return View("Inscricao", db.Cursos.ToList());

        var alunoCurso = new AlunoCurso {
            Aluno = aluno, 
            Curso = curso}
        };

        db.AlunoCursos.Add(alunoCurso);
        db.SaveChanges();

        curso.Qtd_Vagas--;
        db.Entry(curso).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();

        scope.Complete();
    }

    return View("Inscricao", db.Cursos.ToList());
}
```

Comment: Fiz as alterações e agora minha página de Inscrição não renderiza @Cigano!