# View não renderiza no asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Galera, sou iniciante no `asp.net` `MVC` e estou apanhando já tem um certo tempo para uma bendita de uma `View`. Conforme a ajuda que eu tive nesse post [Botão só funciona se passar o Id na URL no asp.net MVC](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/67560/bot%C3%A3o-s%C3%B3-funcionar-se-passar-o-id-na-url-no-asp-net-mvc/67579#67579)

Seguindo o exemplo fiz minhas adaptações mas agora minha `View` não está renderizando. Alguém pode me dar uma força?!

Fiz assim uma Action **GET** retornando a `View` e a página renderizou, porém, a ação do meu botão não faz nada, nem entra no `breakpoint`.

```
    //GET
    public ActionResult Inscricao()
    {
        return View(db.Cursos);
    }

    //POST
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Inscricao(int inscricaoId)
    {
        using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            Aluno aluno = db.Alunos.FirstOrDefault();
            if (aluno == null)
                return View("Inscricao", db.Cursos.ToList());

            var curso = db.Cursos.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == inscricaoId);
            if (curso == null)
                return View("Inscricao", db.Cursos.ToList());

            var alunoCurso = new AlunoCurso
            {
                Aluno = aluno,
                Curso = curso
            };

            db.AlunoCursos.Add(alunoCurso);
            db.SaveChanges();

            curso.Qtd_Vagas--;
            db.Entry(curso).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();

            scope.Complete();
        }

        return View(db.Cursos.ToList());

    }
```

**Erro POST**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Lista de Cursos**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu botão após o clique também deveria ser desabilitado conforme código abaixo. Só que não está desabilitando.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#inscricao").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Inscricao/",
                data: {inscricaoId: $(this).data("inscricaoid")},
                success: function() {
                        $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
                    }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Adicione os códigos que chama a View

Comment: O que aparece no console log do navegador quando você clica no botão?

Comment: Apareceu 3 erros **GET** @MaiconCarraro

Comment: Mostra quais são

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Substitua

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <a href="@Url.Action("Inscricao", "Curso")">
            <input type="submit" value="Inscrição" name="inscricao" class="inscricao btn btn-success" data-toggle ="modal", data-target="#modalaviso" data-inscricaoid="@item.CursoId" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Por

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Inscricao", "Curso", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <a class="inscricao btn btn-success" onclick="$(this).parents('form').submit()">Inscrição</a>
            <input type="hidden" value="@item.CursoId" name="inscricaoId" />
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Dessa forma nem precisa do script criado anteriormente e faz tudo numa requisição só.

-

-

<strike>Analisando o código da outra pergunta, você provavelmente deixou nó codigo essa linha:</strike>

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Inscricao", "Curso")">
```

Com o novo script não precisa mais dele porque você já faz a requisição por POST na hora que clicar no `input`. Remova ele da página.

-

**Solução antiga:**

Vendo pelo seu erro está errado na requisição ajax mesmo, troque

```
url: "~/Curso/Inscricao/",
```

por

```
url: "Inscricao/",
```

Ficando

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".inscricao").click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Inscricao/",
                    data: { inscricaoId: $(this).data("inscricaoid") }
                    success: function() {
                        window.location.reload();
                    }
                });
            });

        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Tirei essa linha ai, agora tá dando esse erro no console vou postar na pergunta @MaiconCarraro

Comment: @Novato Atualizei com a resposta

Comment: Valeu @MaiconCarraro funcionou, porém, quando a quantidade de vagas é decrementada a pagina não atualiza automaticamente tenho que apertar F5.

Comment: @Novato Onde está exibindo as vagas?

Comment: Vou postar na pergunta @MaiconCarraro juntamente com o Ajax que chama essa View

Comment: ainda continua do mesmo jeito.

Comment: Estou pensando em outra solução, de colocar um form em volta do seu botão ou simplesmente redirecionar a página quando recebe o `success`

Comment: @Novato eu adicionei `window.location.reload();` dentro do `success`, eu estou indo para casa agora quando chegar lá posto a outra solução com form.

Comment: @Novato Pronto, atualizei com a outra solução

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24521/discussion-between-novato-and-maicon-carraro).